# Laravel POST request gives me a 404

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently writing an API in Laravel, and I've hit a bit of a snag. At the moment I'm focussed on the Authentication part of my api, so I have the following routes:

(Via `php artisan route:list`)

```
+--------+--------+------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method | URI                    | Name | Action                                                 | Middleware |
+--------+--------+------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | POST   | v1/users/auth/login    |      | App\Http\Controllers\User\AuthController@login         | api        |
|        | POST   | v1/users/auth/register |      | App\Http\Controllers\User\AuthController@register      | api        |
+--------+--------+------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Very simple. Now, when I try to post to `v1/users/auth/login` through Postman, it works. It gives me the expected responses and everything. However, when I try the `register` route, Laravel throws up a 404?

No errors, no nothing, just a 404. Now through some caveman debugging I can see that it passes through the `authorize()` method of the request, but then it throws that darn error again.

This is my request:

```
class RegistrationRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return !Auth::check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'code' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ];
    }

   public function persist() 
   {
      $user = User::create([
            'username' => $this->username,
            'password' => password_hash($this->password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            'reg_ip' => $this->ip(),
            'last_ip' => $this->ip()
        ]);
       return response()->json($user->api_token, 201);
   }
```

How how is that possible, as my route is cleary defined?

Thanks.

-- EDIT:

my controller:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(RegistrationRequest $request)
    {
        return $request->persist();
    }

    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        return $request->persist();
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your blade file which contains form

Comment: Can you provide the code for login function at AuthController and the file which it should be returning?

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta _"I'm currently writing an API"_, _" try to post to v1/users/auth/login through Postman"_. There's no blade file.

Comment: @BonishKoirala Updated the questionn :)

Answer (score 1):

To call api routes in laravel add api/ as prefix to the route or else it will search for routes in web.php

Answer (score 0):

add prefix on this route

```
v1/users/auth/login
```

use like this

```
api/v1/users/auth/login
```